# Resolving conflicts results in no changes added

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Let's say I have a `master` branch, and a `feature-a` branch. `feature-a` is up for review but everyone is busy. I need to start `feature-b` but `feature-b` is dependent on code done in `feature-a`.

So up until now I've been branching `feature-b` from `feature-a` , and then merging down any changes that might happen to `feature-a`.

Now let's say someone gets freed up, and passes `feature-a`, therefore `feature-a` gets merged into `master`.

Now it's time to sync `feature-b` with `master`. Whether I rebase or merge `master` down to `feature-b`, often I end up with conflicts that, when resolved, result in no changes to commit, which means I can't commit.

I've done some googling and literally the only viable solution seems to be:

1. Merge master into feature-b causing merge conflicts.
2. Make another change mid-resolve (e.g. a comment or something)
3. Resolve the conflicts (leading to only one change, the comment)
4. Commit

This seems bonkers to me :thinking_face:

Does anyone know of a better way of resolving the conflicts/managing my branches in the above situation?

Answer (score 1):

Draw the commits you have.  Really, literally, draw the graph of commits, on paper or a whiteboard or whatever (or let `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` draw it for you, but you'll get more out of this if you do it by hand).  You will end up with something that looks like this:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master
            \
             A--B--C--D   <-- feature-a
                       \
                        E--F--G   <-- feature-b
```

*before* the someone-else gets freed up and merges `feature-a`.  (The letters stand in for raw hash IDs.)  Then, someone else gets freed up and merges `feature-a`.  So, *draw* that:

```
...--o--o--*------------M   <-- master
            \          /
             A--B--C--D   <-- feature-a
                       \
                        E--F--G   <-- feature-b
```

If they did the merge some other way, or if other commits got merged first, draw *that*.  Draw the actual graph!  It's important, because it is how Git works.

Now consider what you'd *like to get* as the final merge result.  Would you prefer:

```
...--o--o--*------------M---------M2   <-- master
            \          /         /
             A--B--C--D         /
                       \       /
                        E--F--G
```

or:

```
...--o--o--*------------M---------M2   <-- master
            \          / \       /
             A--B--C--D   E'-F'-G'   <--- feature-b
                       \
                        E--F--G   [abandoned, do not use]
```

or something else entirely?

It sounds like you're going for this second option, which is most easily obtained with `git rebase`: rebase *copies* commits.  We need to copy `E` to new commit `E'`, which is like `E` but comes after `M` (uses `M` as its predecessor and when compared to `M`, makes the same *changes* as `E` did compared to `D`).  Then we need to copy `F` to `F'` and `G` to `G'`.

If you just run `git rebase master`, Git sometimes<sup>1</sup> chooses *too many* commits to copy.  In particular, it might—not in the example I drew here, but in other cases—decide that it should copy `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` first.

When Git decides to do that, you'll get the kind of merge conflicts you're seeing, because everything that each of these commits did, is already done.  When you resolve these merge conflicts, you're left with nothing to commit.

The `git rebase` command has an answer for that: in mid-rebase, after resolving these conflicts, you run `git rebase --skip`.  But it's often easier to do your rebase in such a way that Git "pre-skips" the four commits that you *don't* want copied.  To do this, you can use `git rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto master feature-a
```

for instance, assuming your name `feature-a` still selects commit `D`.  (Remember that branch names *move* over time, while commits themselves, as identified by their hash IDs, never change.)

The `--onto` tells rebase where to put the copies: after `M`.  The `feature-a` part tells Git what *not* to copy: the commit identified by `feature-a`, and any earlier commits reachable by starting at that commit and working backwards through the graph.  (The commits to be copied are always those that end wherever your `HEAD` is now, and the branch name to be moved at the end of the process, so as to abandon the old commits in favor of the new-and-improved chain, is the branch *name* you're on right now.)

Drawing the graph is the key to many of Git's operations.

---

<sup>1</sup>This depends on both the *graph* and the results of running `git patch-id` on each commit.  In the graph drawn here, in which `feature-a` was literally merged as-is, Git would know not to copy `A-B-C-D` as those commits, with whatever their raw hash IDs are, are *reachable from* the name `master`, working back along the second parent of merge commit `M`.  So this is not the correct graph drawing.